# I return Response with `status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND` but find the 201

Tags: python, django

In the views.py, I return Response with `status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND`:

```
class CloudServerCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CloudServerCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = CloudServer.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):

        return Response(data="There is no data left.", status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, exception=Exception())

        serializer.save()
```

But when I request the API, I get `HTTP 201 Created`, not the `404`:

```
POST /api/user_productmanage/cloudserver/create/
HTTP 201 Created
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "expiration_time": "2017-12-11T11:11:11+08:00",
    "profile": "asdas",
    "buytime": 1,
    "availablearea": 2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 404 logic should not live in the perform_create. Perform create is mainly used to inject data you calculate elsewhere or user specific.

For instance `serializer.save(user=self.request.user, date_time=datetime.now())`.

Try moving your logic to `create` or `post` method. My suggestion would be to move it to `post`.

```
class CloudServerCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CloudServerCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = CloudServer.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Your reason for 404
        # if reason:
        #     # return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Your reason for 404
        if reason:
            return Response(data="There is no data left.", status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, exception=Exception())
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```